# Have a list of items in lambda event

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Lambda Function has event as its input which is in JSON format.

Example -
`event = {'a' : '1', 'b' : '2'}`

Can I have a list assigned to one of the keys like -

`event = {'a' : ['1','3'],'b' : '2'}`

Which format will it be in? Str or list?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What's the input? What's the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can put lists in JSON.

Comment: It will take it as a list or string?

Comment: JSON is a string. When you parse it, it becomes an object and lists inside it becomes lists. Your example should work.